# How to successfully calculate value from a child in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, integer

I am trying to calculate the sum of value of all children in the databse with the name "Price"

below is my code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        mtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textre);
        mda = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart");
        mda.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue();
                    Object price = map.get("Price");
                    int pvalue = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(price));
                    sum += pvalue;
                    if (sum<100){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"greare",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sorry",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

as shown in my code if the value obtained from the price nodes is less than 100 then a toast message should appear saying "success". Instead, the app crushes with no message

the image is a view of my firebase database showing the values "Price" I wish to obtain

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this, I think that you are not getting the Price value right

```
mda.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                int pvalue = ds.child("Price").getValue(Integer.class);
                sum += pvalue;
                if (sum<100){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"greare",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sorry",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but the app is still crashing without any message

Comment: its rare that it crashes without any message, did you see the logcat?

Comment: I don't have an emulator installed on my PC to run the app from android studio, so I sent the apk to my phone and tested it from there, and the app crashed

Comment: yes, if you dont plug your phone into your pc to debug it with android studio there is nothing we can do, debugging is part of software development

Comment: I have done as you said and there is no error message but the log cat is there.let me send it

Comment: 2019-07-04 20:41:10.302 554-4683/? E/RMS.HwSysResManagerService: Process Permission error! pid:1742 uid:1001 Process.myPid:554
2019-07-04 20:41:10.329 554-564/? E/RMS.HwSysResManagerService: Process Permission error! pid:1742 uid:1001 Process.myPid:554
2019-07-04 20:41:10.378 670-670/? E/Thermal-daemon: [pa_0] temp_new :36  temp_old :35

Comment: I don't really know what particular error should be focussed on though

Comment: No I did not, but could that really be the problem? There's an element of Google maps in the app and it works fine

Comment: to request data from firebase you should put the permission inside your manifest

Comment: Ohhh, okay I understand . Do I only put the internet permission or do I have to add something else related to firebase? Or just the internet permission will do?

Comment: just the internet permission should be fine

Comment: I apologize for my earlier response, I am getting this in the logcat....., java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference at com.bwae.kuja.Main2Activity$1.onDataChange